Subspaces of $C_0$ on which $p$-norm are equivalent?
I have a question concerning the generalization of the following fact.
Let $E = C^0([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ endowed with the $\|.\|_\infty$ norm. One can show that if $F$ is a subspace of $E$ for which there exists $C < \infty$ such that, for any $f \in F$, one has $$ \|f\|_\infty \leq C \|f\|_2 $$ then $F$ has finite dimension.
I suppose this hold if one take a $\|.\|_p$ norm with $p>2$ instead of the $\|.\|_2$ norm but I cannot find a solution since the original solution uses the fact that $\|.\|_2$ comes from a inner product.
Does anyone has a proof or a counterexample ?

If you need a reference, the argument in Giorgio Metafune's answer is used in Grothendieck's theorem about closed subspaces of $L^p$ contained in $L^\infty$ which is theorem 5.2 in Rudin's Functional Analysis.

I have just checked it, thanks !

Use $\|f\|_p \leq \|f\|_\infty^{1- \frac 2p}\|f\|_2^{\frac 2 p}$ to get $\|f\|_\infty \leq C\|f\|_2$ from $\|f\|_\infty \leq C\|f\|_p$.

Thank you !  :-)
